# how to send an company logo with email

Tags: jquery

I want to send an email with Spring MVC. That portion is completed but in the message body I want to send a logo of a company. I'm stuck on that. I tried with `contentEditable`, but it's still no use. When sending I am not able to get the logo of an image.

```
<div id="msgBody" contentEditable="true" style="border: 1px solid #d6d1d1; border-radius: 8px;">
  <br/><br/>
  Thanks and Regards,<br/>
  Penta&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" style="vertical-align: middle; height: 40px; width: 40px;">
</div>
```

I'm using this jQuery to get the text of the div:

```
var contenteditable = document.querySelector('[contenteditable]'),
text = contenteditable.textContent;
console.log(text);
```

Comment: Relative paths don't work in emails. The URL to the image needs to be an absolute path, eg `http://yourwebsite.com/images/logo.png`

Comment: i saved the logo of a company in my image folder....my questions is that i am getting the value of the text but how can i send the image along with it

Comment: Yes, but the URL to it is wrong when the user receives the email. As I mentioned above, you need to use an absolute URL